# Error 404 - The requested resource is not available in Eclipse with tomcat 7

Tags: eclipse, tomcat, web-applications, eclipse-wtp

I am trying to run a simple web-app with eclipse and tomcat 7.
I an index html file with a text input and a submit button that calls on servlet.

I have created a Dynamic web project and have put the html (index.html) file in the WebContent folder.

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>title</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="/TestServ" method="get">
        <input type="text" name="input">
        <input type="submit" value="Send it!">
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

I have my package com.testing.web under  /Java Rescources/src
and in it my servlet (TestServ.java) which looks loke this:

```
@WebServlet("/TestServ")
public class TestServ extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#HttpServlet()
     */
    public TestServ() {
        super();
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        System.out.println("AA%WU^SDJI&^R&KU");
    }

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        System.out.println("AA%WU^SDJI&^R&KU");
    }
}
```

When i select Run->run on server on the project the index.html file loads just fine.
The problem is that when i submit the form i get the following error page:

```
HTTP Status 404 - /TestServ

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

type Status report

message /TestServ

description The requested resource is not available.


--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Apache Tomcat/7.0.34
```

I have searched and searched and haven't found a solution that helps me.
Most answers around the web point to servlet url mapping mistakes.
Note that i have tried many of them to no avail.

Furthermore i would like to add that my server is configured to use jdk1.7.0_10 in the runtime enviroments oprtion.

Finally, i do not understand why eclipse doesn't create the proper class/ structure under WEB-INF when the project is built.

I am totally buffled and any help will be much appreciated.
Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: whats your complete url ?

Comment: If the application is properly deployed (that has to be checked in the logs), the url of your servlet is http://.../[name-of-the-war]/TestServ but double check you have not any issue in tomcat logs. BTW, do you see your "AA%WU^SDJI&^R&KU" in the output?

Comment: Thanks for the replies.
Tech- my url is http://localhost:9999/TestProj/, which brings up the index.html and after that when i click on the submit button its: http://localhost:9999/TestServ?input=   whixh gives me the error.

Comment: ZNK-M - I'm not sure how to check the logs of the server instance inside eclipse :/
On the other hand, my output message is shown in the console only if i do Run->run on server directly on the servlet file. When i go through the index and submit process it doesn't.

Answer (score 4):

Finally found the problem, and as usual it was the simplest thing.

The action in the form needed to be like this:

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>title</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="/TestProj/TestServ" method="get">
        <input type="text" name="input">
        <input type="submit" value="Send it!">
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

and the url mapping as follows:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>TestServ</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.testing.web.TestServ</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>TestServ</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/TestServ</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
```

frankly i don't perfectly understand why though. Shouldn't /Testproj be considered the root of the app anyway? :/ 
Anyway...

Comment: This was the 7th *The requested resource is not available* SO question I read. Finally! **/TestProj/TestServ** not **/TestServ**.

Answer (score 0):

in order to remove 404 error we have to check the web.xml and the url you are giving in the tab. url should be like
 http://<127.0.0.1:8080>//. if it is webservice application

Answer (score -1):

Nothing wrong with your server configuration. Need some modifications in web.xml file. Just try this!

1. Open your "web.xml" file.
2. Add these tags between "`<display-name>`" tag & "`<welcome-file-list>`" tag.

   `<servlet>
       <servlet-name>TestServ</servlet-name>
       <servlet-class>TestServ</servlet-class>
     </servlet>`

   `<servlet-mapping>
       <servlet-name>TestServ</servlet-name>
       <url-pattern>/TestServ</url-pattern>
     </servlet-mapping>`
3. Run your project and in browser enter URL as "http://localhost:8080/TestServ"

### Hope it will work! :)

P.S.
* You can actually use any name between "`<servlet-name>`" tags. But names in both places must be same.